# mysqldump on mariadb 10 extremely slow

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, aws, database, mariadb

I'm running a MariaDB 10.1.34 instance on AWS RDS. Instance specs are as follows:

- Instance Class: db.t2.large
- Storage: 100GiB gp2
- DB Size: 1.2 GiB

I'm trying to create a mysqdump from an EC2 instance located in the same availability zone as the db. While this works, the performance is extremely bad. It takes around 15 minutes to dump the database ( which is only 1.2 GiB in size ) with mysqldump.

I've been monitoring disk and network usage on the ec2 instance. In the first 5 seconds of mysqldump, network usage spikes around 600 Mbit/s and then dropping to only around 200 kbit/s. Same with the disk usage.

Strangely, rebooting the Database instance seems to fix the behaviour temporarily. mysqldump finished in 30 seconds one time, and became slow again afterwards.

The Write IOPS on the DB instance hover around 10 - 15, Read iops only exceeded 20 after restarting the instance.

I'd be grateful for any advice on how to debug this issue further.

EDIT:

I should also add my mysqldump command:

```
ubuntu@server:~$ mysqldump --version
mysqldump  Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.7.23, for Linux (x86_64)
ubuntu@server:~$ mysqldump -h <db_host> -p -P 3306 -u <read_only_user> --quick --single-transaction --skip-lock-tables <database> > dump.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic case where you've been hit by **T2/T3 burstable performance**.

As you may know when T2/T3 instances are idle they accumulate "CPU credits" that they then use for running fast when needed. However these credits deplete when the instance is running at full speed and when there are none left the instance slows down. See here for more details: [CPU Credits and Baseline Performance for Burstable Performance Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-credits-baseline-concepts.html)

Although the above only talks about *CPU credits* from experience I know it directly affects *network performance* as well, although I wasn't able to find any document in that regard from Amazon. And that's what you observed too.

To work around it you've got 2 options:

1. Switch to **M4 / M5 instance type** - these have constant performance and are not affected by CPU credits. They are slightly more expensive than T2 / T3 thuogh.
2. Enable **T2 unlimited** setting ([see here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-t2-unlimited-going-beyond-the-burst-with-high-performance/)) that will top-up your instance credits whenever they drop to 0 for some extra cost. It may be the best option for your use case. However note that running T2 unlimited at full speed all the time is more expensive than running M4 instance of the same size.